# Send post data in list of model that contain list of other model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model

I need to send post request that contain data of model that contain list of other model

Correct format for request with tools like "rested" for chrome?

```
public class ModelTestRequest
{
    List<ModelTestChild> GoodList { get; set; }

}
public class ModelTestChild
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
public class Modeltestresponse
{
    public List<ModelTestChild> GoodList2 { get; set; }
} 


public Modeltestresponse SpecialName(ModelTestRequest model)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved

- Content-Type = "application/json"
- param name "GoodList1"
- param value "[{"description":"hi","id":1}]"
- link http://192.168.1.200:50670/api/SpecialName
- method post

Answer (score 0):

Post data , as in you require it in JSON?